# Nextjs PizZip Library "window is not defined" error

Tags: next.js, docxtemplater, pizzip

Im using PizZip library in my Nextjs project to use with Docxtemplater.
But I got an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4fiT.png)

I checked the library file and found it uses window object.
I guess it tries to access window object before the page load. (at the prerendering).
How can I solve that problem?

I havent tried something yet. Also im getting the same error about window object at the build time.

SOLVED:

I have solved the problem just now. I removed the component (my modal that uses PizZip library to use Docxtemplater) from layout.js file and I moved it to a client component.
It works rn. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you edit this question and add the relevent code?

Comment: I have solved the problem just now. I removed the component (my modal that uses PizZip library to use Docxtemplater) from layout.js file and I moved it to a client component.
It works rn. Thanks for your answer.